# Splitting BTC and BCH from cold storage using bitcoin core wallet sending to exodus

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-qt-setup, exodus

I had BTC long before the forks of BCH (bitcoin cash) and any of the others.

I wanted to finally split some BCH off of my BTC and so this is what I attempted to do

1. Bitcoin Core Wallet Send to Exodus Wallet
2. I verified the blockchain and refreshed Exodus and I see  .023 BTC  ( $181.41 currently)  .
3. I clicked on Help in Exodus and the claim your bitcoin cash in which it is supposed to scan to see if I have any BCH
4. It says none found.

Either this is not how to find the BCH and split it of, or .023 BCH is too small of an amount ?

What other decent options are there as I want to split up at least the BCH from the BTC .

Comment: Rutger's answer is correct, but in general if you search online (or on this site) you'll find plenty of resources explaining how to claim your BCH in a safe way.

Comment: @chytrik    Hi , I was seeing  Exodus, Electron and a ton of conflicting articles , is there any articles you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import the keys from your bitcoin core wallet to the exodus wallet?

It seems to me that you simply transacted your bitcoins to another adress (+Wallet).

This however does not mean that your bitcoin cash will also be send to that adress ( unless there was no replay transaction of course.(Which there is))

Your bitcoin cash is still at the adress where your bitcoin was at the time of the split.
Import that adress ( or rather the private key) into a bitcoin cash compatible wallet and you should see your BCH balance.

Comment: I simply did a send from btc core wallet to the btc receive address in exodus .    So it sounds like ALL of my BCH is still in the btc core address , in that it didn't even send a portion of it ..

Comment: So it sounds like I should import keys of the bitcoin core wallet into exodus ... and close core and then exodus will have the entire btc /bch  .   Is this a recommended way, or is using electrum or sending it to online place recommended?

Comment: You can also import the keys of your bitcoin core wallet into electrum cash. yes. Make sure to check signatures of any wallet you download thhough, you don't want to get phished/scammed. Also read my answer again. Bitcoin cash has replay protection. they're seperate entities. If you spent bitcoin it doesn't mean that you spent bitcoin cash aswell. The only thing they currently have in common is that they're derived the same way  ( both belonging to the same private key). They both have seperate blockchains

Answer (score 1):

The transaction you sent to Exodus moved your BTC, but BCH is a different network. Your bitcoin core wallet and the exodus wallet both interact with the BTC network, so anything you do using them will not affect the BCH at all.

If you'd like to claim your BCH, you'll need to do the following:

First, send ALL of the bitcoin out of your wallet. This is important, it ensures the keys that control your bitcoin remain safe. If the BCH software you use in the next step is malicious for some reason, it might check the BTC balance of the addresses you control, and steal the bitcoin from you.

Next, export the private keys from bitcoin core. You'll need to create a BCH wallet using BCH specific software, and import the keys for any addresses that have a BCH balance. You can use a BCH block explorer website to check which addresses hold a balance, in case you're unsure.

At that point, your BCH wallet will show your BCH balance, and you are free to spend it as you wish.

Worth mentioning: don't transfer the btc back to the same bitcoin core wallet afterwards. If you'd like to keep using bitcoin core, you'll want to start a new wallet, since you old private keys have been compromised by being input into the BCH software.

Comment: 1. send all btc to exodus ?  2. bch software , exodus bch wallet or a different bch specific software ?

Comment: You'll need to first send your BTC to a BTC wallet, and then find BCH wallet software capable of importing your keys. Its up to you to choose which wallets you use, I have no personal experience using Exodus, so I'm unsure if they support BCH (including importation of BCH private keys). Worth mentioning: any time you are choosing wallet software, be prudent. Don't just take the advice of a single person online, do your research and find software that has a good history of reviews across many websites.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers were helpful,  but ultimately I transferred from bitcoin core wallet to Electron Cash.

I used this link  https://graspingtech.com/claim-bitcoin-cash-bitcoin-core-wallet/

pay attention to the comments, as the Electron Cash UI changed a bit.